# Error with "rails -v"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, macos, rubygems

I'm working on Mac Snow Leapord

Prior to installation of RVM, I have tried (but failed) upgrading OSX's default ruby.

Installation of Ruby was done with

```
rvm install 1.9.2
```

with `ruby -v` :

```
ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [x86_64-darwin10.7.0]
```

gem is 1.7.2
Installed rails with `sudo gem install rails`
Rails installed with no errors prompted.

With `rails -v` :

```
/Users/kyle/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:926:in `report_activate_error': Could not find RubyGem rails (>= 0) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /Users/kyle/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:244:in `activate_dep'
    from /Users/kyle/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:236:in `activate'
    from /Users/kyle/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1307:in `gem'
    from /Users/kyle/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/rails:18:in `<main>'
```

I do have gem installed, otherwise I wouldn't have been able to do `gem install rails`

Does anyone knows the cause or a solution to this ?

Comment: have you done gem update --system ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you used sudo to install rails when you are using rvm.  Try this:

```
$ rvm use 1.9.2
$ gem install rails
```

HTH

Comment: To be clear, this is because if you're using `rvm` then `sudo gem` will be using a different ruby installation to `gem`. So you *did* previously install rails, but not to anywhere that `rvm` will be looking for it

Comment: Sudo is just a way to run command as another user.  When you don't specify a particular user, it assumes root.  So, in your case, `sudo gem install rails` installs rails under whatever the default ruby implementation for root is.  Glad this worked out for you!

Answer (score 1):

Do `gem install rails` (not sudo) to install for the current user?